# How to go to specific page with VFR pdf reader library with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, pdf-reader, vfr-reader

I'm using vfr reader to display my pdf file (https://github.com/vfr/Reader). One of my iOS app function is to go to specific page of the pdf file.

I didn't find any API in the source code could help me to do so. 
But I see one of the property
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSNumber *pageNumber;

However, it can only be set during init process.
Is there any easy and rational way to go to the specific page?

Answer (score 1):

To go to the specific page, I open the follow interface.

```
[_ReadViewContrller showDocumentPage:_PageNumber]
```